# ERROR: libvpx decoder version must be >=0.9.1

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

Heyo! 
I'm trying to install ffmpeg on my server using the following tutorial:
https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuideLucid
When I reach the ffmpeg part and run the ./configure command it gives the following error:

```
ERROR: libvpx decoder version must be >=0.9.1
```

I must mention that my server has Ubunto 10.10 64bit
I'm a total newbie in linux so please take it into consideration :)
Thanks a lot!

Following LordNeckBeard solution, I got the following error after the checkinstall:

```
root@348588:~/libvpx# sudo checkinstall --pkgname=libvpx --pkgversion="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)-git" --backup=no--default --deldoc=yes

checkinstall 1.6.2, Copyright 2009 Felipe Eduardo Sanchez Diaz Duran
           This software is released under the GNU GPL.


no--default is an invalid value for --backup

Use --help or -h to get more information
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indicates that libvpx did not install properly or you have an old version of libvpx that is version <0.9.1.

Your first step is to check if libvpx did install. If you get the following if it is installed:

```
$ dpkg -s libvpx | grep Status
Status: install ok installed
```

If it is not installed:

```
$ dpkg -s libvpx | grep Status
Status: unknown ok not-installed
```

It might be a good idea to remove `libvpx-dev` if present so it doesn't possibly interfere with ffmpeg detecting your compiled libvpx:

```
sudo apt-get remove libvpx-dev
```

Then try installing libvpx again:

```
cd ~/libvpx
make clean
git pull
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=libvpx --pkgversion="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)-git" --backup=no --default --deldoc=yes
```

Now try ffmpeg again:

```
cd ~/ffmpeg
make distclean
git pull
```

Then continue with the guide as shown beginning with the ffmpeg `./configure` line.

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly detailed solution however in the fourth part of your solution - last line. seems that it doesn't work. that's what I got 
root@348588:~/libvpx# sudo checkinstall --pkgname=libvpx --pkgversion="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)-git" --backup=no--default --deldoc=yes

checkinstall 1.6.2, Copyright 2009 Felipe Eduardo Sanchez Diaz Duran
           This software is released under the GNU GPL.


no--default is an invalid value for --backup

Comment: and I also tried to continue the ffmpeg installation anyway, it didn't work!

Comment: @BaseemNajjar The complete checkinstall console output properly formatted and included in your original question will be helpful.

Comment: @BaseemNajjar You're missing a space between `--backup=no` and `--default`.

Comment: @AlexTran Added your edit that shouldn't have been rejected.

Comment: If you have built libraries for making ffmpeg, like libvpx, remember to run `sudo ldconfig` after you have installed them and before you try configure in ffmpeg.

See http://www.frasq.org/en/transcoding-an-audio-or-a-video-file.

Answer (score 0):

look at the tail of ./ffmpeg/config.log to double check what exactly the issue is and to rule out any ambiguity in the error msg reported.

if it is a version error on vpx , you can manually go to git and get a newer vpx version checked out into the vpx folder ..

see [here](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=webm/libvpx.git) for the various newer tags you can check out using git.

then, rerun the config/ make/ install steps in the vpx folder as per your orig process

rerun the ffmpeg/configure in order to resolve orig error